# Webpack, "hot-reload" or "live-reload" sass?

Tags: sass, reload, webpack

Is there a way to get webpack to "recompile" sass and reload your page on the fly?

I've been searching around but have not found an example.

Here is what I've got:

My folder structure

```
-app
---public
------dist
---------index.html
---------sass
------------webpack.scss
```

It seems like my sass only recompiles when I run `webpack` but it doesn't recompile when I am running the `webpack-dev-server`

```
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './app/main.js',
    //All 3rd party source
    vendor: ['react', 'redux', 'lodash']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'public', 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/app/public/dist/',
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'], exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.css/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css') },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('!css!sass?sourceMap') }
    ]
  },
  sassLoader: {
    includePaths: [ path.resolve(__dirname, './app/public/sass/')]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("vendor", "vendor.js", Infinity),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('./css/style.css',{
            allChunks: true
        })
  ],
  debug: true,
  //watch: true
};
```

Comment: Looks like I had a hot-reload error, had to start webpack using node (since I included new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin() )

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you solved this? I've got a similar issue.